# Sew a dead cat from fake fur

Tags: microphone

I was wondering if I could sew a dead cat (furry microphone cover) from normal fake fur I could get at a fabric store or is the fabric used for a dead cat significantly different from fake fur?

[image]

pic from http://www.auphotographer.com.au/

Comment: can you be more specific about what you describe as fake fur and dead cat. maybe use some images?

Answer (score 3):

The main reason why dead cats are used is that the hairs deaden the noise caused by the shock of wind hitting the blimp - they absorb energy at a wide range of frequencies before the mic can pick it up.

So realistically, any long haired fake fur will work. Whether or not the type you can get at a local fabric store will be as good, I don't know. Sound companies will, I assume, have sourced the type that works best in their tests, but I can't imagine that this will be measurable by amateur/semi-pro kit.

Many individuals make their own - just google for fur mic cover or fur windscreens for many examples.

Answer (score 1):

My friend made fur covers for his drums and I had some leftovers to make windshield for my DR-100. It works nice with a light breeze but I think the material is too light for heavier wind. Making one of these won't cost much so it's definitely worth trying :)